# __int64 formatting output to hex

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I want to convert __int64 type param into `CString`. But I always get the wrong output.
Here is my code:

```
__int64 = offset;//non zero
CString strOutput;
strOutput.Format(_T("0x%x"), offset);
```

The wrong output is: 0x0

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
strOutput.Format(_T("0x%llx"), offset);
```

or even better, if you can `#include <inttypes.h>`:

```
strOutput.Format(_T("0x%"PRIx64""), offset);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
strOutput.Format(_T("0x%I64X"), offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
strOutput.Format(_T("%I64d"),offset);
```

Comment: i don't think that prints hex.  does it?

Comment: EDITED: No that does not, but that is an aswer to OP's question "I want to convert __int64 type param into CString" :)

Comment: that's not my question... my question is: *i don't think that prints hex. does it?*